# getting replacement PCIe-NVMe SSDs

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, lenovo-laptop, pci-express

In the past when I bought laptop's I'd get the smallest / cheapest (SATA) HDD available and then swap it out with a better one from newegg.com.

This one particular laptop I'm now looking at comes with a PCIe-NVMe SSD. My question is...  how interchangeable are those? They're not soldered onto the motherboard, are they?

When I do a search on newegg.com for "SSD PCIe-NVMe" I get cards that are obviously for desktop's, motherboards and cards that appear to be for laptop's. There are two interfaces: PCI-Express 3.0 and PCI-Express 3.0 x4. There are 4x form factors: 2.5", AIC, M.2 and M.2 2280. How do I know which of these I need? Are some of these form factors / interfaces for laptop's only?

The laptop in question is a ThinkPad P50.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt visit the [Manufacturer's Website](http://www3.lenovo.com/au/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-p-series/P50/p/22TP2WPWP50#tab-tech_specs). Their website lists the laptop as having the capabilities of 2 M.2 SSDs and one HDD. The website does get a little bit convoluted though, however it seems to be that there are TWO M.2 slots along with a SATA3 slot. The M.2 slots are fed by the PCIe lanes instead of SATA3 lanes, so in this situation you'd be looking for PCIe M.2 drives. If in doubt, crack open the laptop and take a look at your current M.2 drive - search up some info on it, and buy something that uses the same interface as it does.

To answer your question, no they are not generally soldered into the motherboard.